Using excel formula returns error The list source must be a delimited list
I created the following formula:
=IF('preview_tile'!$F2="France"; 'Creative Format'!AC2:AC14; IF('preview_tile'!$F2="Canada"; 'Creative Format'!AB2:AB13;IF('preview_tile'!$F2="India"; 'Creative Format'!AD2:AD14; IF('preview_tile'!$F2="United States";'Creative Format'!AA2:AA20; IF('preview_tile'!$F2="Germany";'Creative Format'!AE2:AE16; IF('preview_tile'!$F2="United Kingdom";'Creative Format'!AZ2:AZ18; ""))))))

When I use this formula for the first cell(G2) is working fine. But if put this formula in Data Validation for another cells, for instance G3, G4 and etc I get error the list source must be a delimited list or a reference to single row or column
No clear for me what wrong with it. Could you please explain

Please edit your question, showing the values of G2, G3, G4, ...

Data validation source must be a list, it cannot be "". change "" to some random empty cell will fix it. =IF('preview_tile'!$F2="France"; 'Creative Format'!AC2:AC14; IF('preview_tile'!$F2="Canada"; 'Creative Format'!AB2:AB13;IF('preview_tile'!$F2="India"; 'Creative Format'!AD2:AD14; IF('preview_tile'!$F2="United States";'Creative Format'!AA2:AA20; IF('preview_tile'!$F2="Germany";'Creative Format'!AE2:AE16; IF('preview_tile'!$F2="United Kingdom";'Creative Format'!AZ2:AZ18; 'Creative Format'!BA2:BA2))))))
